# Where can I see the commit history on the gitHub website?

Tags: github, commit, history

I am looking for the history button on gitHub for all the past git commits.

These are buttons on the gitHub page.

Code
Issues
Pull requests
Actions
Projects
Wiki
Security
Insights
Settings
1 branch
0 tags

Comment: Click on the Code tab and look on the little blue bar.  Or just search the word "commits" on that page if your eyes aren't finding it.

Comment: I just want to say thanks for asking because, you'd think the answer is obvious, but it wasn't for me.

Comment: Seems like things have become iteratively stranger and less intuitive since MS took over. I switched to gitlab 3 years ago and get frustrated every time I have to use GH.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

On the repository page there is commits button below the Big Green Pull-Down Code button to see all commits. Clicking on it will open all the history

[image: Easiest way to see the commit history]

Comment: Just to clarify - "Code button" means the big green pull-down button - it's not the "<> code" tab. The link you're looking for is in the top-right corner of the table showing the files in the repo. The link isn't highlighted (at least, for me) - it's just normal text colour.

Comment: Only exists for people with GitHub pro accounts or on public repositories on free GitHub account :(

Comment: That's an interesting decision... the commit history is one of our most valuable features, we should use the smallest most obscure link on the page for that.

Comment: Yes, it is a super annoying thing as it is a really important thing to check! I am also missing the handy search in the history, very very much.

Answer (score 0):

On the repository page there is a button labeled with three dots that has a pull-down menu. One of the options on this pull-down menu is "Commits":

[image]

[Note: this should just be a correction to the answer by @Hamza Mughal, but when I tried to edit that answer I get an error that the "Edit queue is full." If someone knows how to paste my picture into the original answer, since it's just an update, that would be great.]